# Firebase: how to get the data when child_added complete

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have a case when I need to fetch all `event` objects. Each `event` object has a property `city_id` which is a relationship key to a single `city` object from the list with all `cities`.

```
...
|- events
|  |- event_id
|  |   |- title
|  |   |- city_id
|
|- cities
|  |- city_id
|  |   |- name
|  |   |- location
...
```

So I a doing something like a `join` query:

```
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

async function getAllEvents() {
    const eventsRef = rootRef.child('events');
    const eventsArray = [];

    await eventsRef.on('child_added', async (snapshot) => {
        const eventObject = snapshot.val();
        const cityObject = await getEventCity(eventObject.city_id);
        eventObject.city = cityObject;
        eventsArray.psuh(eventObject);
    });

    return eventsArray;
}

function getEventCity(cityId) {
    return rootRef.child('cities')
        .child(cityId)
        .once('value', (venue) => {
            return venue.val();
        });
}
```

Everything works well with the queries. The problem is that I want to get all events in an array, but the following code doesn't work:

```
const allEvents = getAllEvents();
```

Event that I have `await` before `eventsRef.on('child_added)` it still returns the initial empty array.

What I am doing wrong and how can I catch this moment when the fetching of all on `.on('child_added')` is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know when loading of the initial data is done is to use a `value` event. I haven't really used `async`/`await` yet, but expect you'll need something like this:

```
async function getAllEvents() {
    const eventsRef = rootRef.child('events');
    const eventsArray = [];

    await eventsRef.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.foreach(function(child) {
        const eventObject = child.val();
        const cityObject = await getEventCity(eventObject.city_id);
        eventObject.city = cityObject;
        eventsArray.push(eventObject);
      });
    });

    return eventsArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I had a lot of problems with `async`/`await` so I've used `Promise.all` where I push each `getEventCity(eventObject.city_id)` request ;)

Comment: i think that eventsRef.once is better solution (its supported promise with then).