# Dart: list clear() function stop adding new element due to order of execution

Tags: list, flutter

I am trying to write a function to fetch data into a list, it first clears the list and adds things into it. It is triggered by a button. I find that the order of execution is not as I expected and I don't know how to fix it:(

Each time I supposed 4 elements are added in each run, after that i clicked another button which trigger a function to print current length of the list, I find that it is actually 4 which mean data is added, but how is the checking in `_getEventData()` run before data input and how I can get the order fixed:

```
  void _getEventData() {
    testinglist.clear();
    debugPrint('right after clear');
    print(testinglist.length);
    fireBaseDB.child('event').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map map = snapshot.value;
      map.keys.toList().forEach((element) {
        fireBaseDB
            .child('event')
            .child(element)
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot innersnapshot) {
          testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);
          debugPrint('after entering');
          print(testinglist.length);
        });
      });
    });
    debugPrint('end entering');
    print(testinglist.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("print data"),
                onPressed: () {
                  debugPrint('before entering');
                  print(testinglist.length);
                  _getEventData();
                },
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("check length"),
                onPressed: _checkingLength,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
  ...
  }

Here is the output:
I/flutter (29921): before entering
I/flutter (29921): 0
I/flutter (29921): right after clear
I/flutter (29921): 0
I/flutter (29921): end entering
I/flutter (29921): 0
I/flutter (29921): after entering
I/flutter (29921): 1
I/flutter (29921): after entering
I/flutter (29921): 2
I/flutter (29921): after entering
I/flutter (29921): 3
I/flutter (29921): after entering
I/flutter (29921): 4
I/flutter (29921): Lets check the length
I/flutter (29921): 4
```

Comment: try add a print function after line `testinglist.clear();`. Check whether the item in list has been cleared ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and find out the problem is the order of execution, but i still have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: how about add `debugPrint('after entering');
    print(testinglist.length);` after line  `testinglist.add(innersnapshot.value);` ?

Comment: I just tried that and I restated my problem in a better manner:( I don't know how to deal with the order of execution here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079637/firebase-how-to-get-the-data-when-child-added-complete

Comment: try use `async-await`.

Answer (score 1):

The catch is that you're using `then()` in a synchronous function. This means that the `then` callback will be executed asynchronously, but the rest of `_getEventData()` is executed straight away, since it's synchronous. What you might want is to turn `_getEventData()` into an `async` function, and use the `await` keyword instead of the `then` function. See [this codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) for more details.