# Firebase, React - Detect when onChildAdded inital run has complete

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I have the following listener, that initially gets all child elements, and then each newly added child elements:

```
 onChildAdded(queryRef, function(messageSnapshot) {
          let data = messageSnapshot.val()
          // The following log is ran multiple times on the inital run(once for each child element)
          console.log(data)

 });
```

I would like to detect when the listener has finished and gathered all the data on the initial run. Currently, it logs each individual child, one at a time. Instead I would just like to log an object  containing all the children's data. In order to this, I need a way to detect when the initial run has complete, and all children have been initially fetched.

After searching, I couldn't find any solutions or built-in methods to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the `reactjs` tag to `javascript` While you may be using ReactJS, nothing in what you shared is specific to ReactJS. By tagging with `javascript` instead of `reactjs` you broaden both the number of people who can help **and** the number of people who may later find help from your question and its answer(s). Going forward, please tag with the tags that are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only `onChildAdded` there is no good way to determine when the initial data has been loaded. You will need to either use `onValue` for that, or use both `onChildAdded` *and* `onValue`.

An example for the second case:

```
let hasLoadedInitialValue = false;
onChildAdded(queryRef, function(messageSnapshot) {
  console.log(hasLoadedInitialValue, messageSnapshot.val());
});
onValue(queryRef, function(messagesSnapshot) {
  hasLoadedInitialValue = true;
});
```

Now you will first see a number of these lines:

> false, <your data>
> false, <your data>
> false, <your data>

And then once all the initial data has been loaded **and** you add a new child node, you will see:

> true, <your data>

This has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend checking out:

- [Is there a way to know in what context Child Added is called? Particularly page load vs. other events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850789/is-there-a-way-to-know-in-what-context-child-added-is-called-particularly-page)
- [How to separate initial data load from incremental children with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978078/how-to-separate-initial-data-load-from-incremental-children-with-firebase)
- [Firebase: how to get the data when child_added complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079637/firebase-how-to-get-the-data-when-child-added-complete)

Many of these posts may use the namespaced JavaScript API, but the link to [Upgrade from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) I gave in answer to your previous question should show you how to convert that code.